# Why accessing the elements of a CvMat in JavaCV is so slow?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I was wondering why there is such a great discrepancy in processing times when accessing the elements of a normal array and a CvMat in JavaCV. Indicatively, when running the following code on my computer it takes 0.8 sec for the normal Java array and more than 26 sec (!) for the CvMat. Any ideas why accessing a CvMat is so slow?

```
// Declare a normal java array and a CvMat (requires JavaCV)
double ArrayJava[][]  = new double[10000][10000];
CvMat ArrayJavaCV = CvMat.create(10000, 10000,CV_32F);

// Get current time
long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

// For each element, initialize with a value, get the value and increase it by 0.1 and put it back
    for(int i=0; i<ArrayJava.length; i++){
        for (int j =0; j<ArrayJava[1].length; j++){  
            ArrayJava[i][j] = i; 
            double val1 = ArrayJava[i][j] + 0.1;
            ArrayJava[i][j] = val1; 
        }
    }
    // Compute processing time        
    long endTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("ArrayJava processing time: "+(endTime1 - startTime1)/1000.+" sec");


    // Perform the same procedure for the CvMat
    long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i=0; i<ArrayJavaCV.rows(); i++){
        for (int j =0; j<ArrayJavaCV.cols(); j++){ 
            ArrayJavaCV.put(i, j, i);
            double val2 = ArrayJavaCV.get(i, j) + 0.1;
            ArrayJavaCV.put(i, j, val2);        
            }
        }

    long endTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("ArrayJavaCV processing time: "+(endTime2 - startTime2)/1000.+" sec");
```

Comment: every time you call put or get, that's a java member function call, which in turn calls a C wrapper function, which again calls a C opencv library function.

Comment: Your code would be more readable if you'd follow Java conventions and name your local vars in lower case.  Ex: CvMat arrayJavaCV = ...

Answer (score 0):

In native languages like C++ it's common practice to use getters (i = getCount()) instead of accessing the field directly (i = mCount). This is an excellent habit for C++ and is often practiced in other object oriented languages like C# and Java, because the compiler can usually inline the access, and if you need to restrict or debug field access you can add the code at any time.

However, this is a bad idea on Java. Virtual method calls are expensive, much more so than instance field lookups. It's reasonable to follow common object-oriented programming practices and have getters and setters in the public interface, but within a class you should always access fields directly.

Without a JIT, direct field access is about 3x faster than invoking a trivial getter. With the JIT (where direct field access is as cheap as accessing a local), direct field access is about 7x faster than invoking a trivial getter.